# Nvda - how to read title h2 above interaction element

Tags: nvda

I have a popup modal and I use nvda but it starts read from the interaction element and doesnt read the title, and I want it to start from the title that above also. Btw I don't have x button.

How can I solve it? Is it setting?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [dialog design pattern](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#dialog_modal) and the [associated example](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/examples/dialog-modal/dialog.html).  The example sounds like exactly what you want.  There's a title on the dialog and it's announced but the focus moves to the first input field.

You didn't post any code so perhaps you're missing the `aria-labelledby` on your dialog that should point to the dialog heading.